# Sleep & Hibernate both failing on new build

Tags: windows-10, sleep, hibernate

Recently upgraded my PC, replacing my motherboard, CPU, RAM, and PSU. I'm on Windows 10. Ever since the upgrade, after putting the computer to sleep, when I wake it back up, it has hard reset at some point after sleep and so it's like I'm turning it on after a shut down. I thought perhaps I need to update my Bios and after doing so, it actually did go to sleep and wake correctly the first time I tried it, but has since failed a few times again so I'm less hopeful.

I'm wondering if it's a PSU issue? Having absolutely no other issues besides this, though, so am a bit perplexed. Any ideas?

**Things I've tried:**
Updated BIOS to latest. Turned ErP mode On (was initially off... just thought I'd try it) Turned off a bunch of the default wake settings on Windows 10 just in case there was some strange scheduled wake things messing with my sleep settings.

**Build details below:**

PCPartPicker Part List: https://pcpartpicker.com/list/3V7qk6

CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 3900X 3.8 GHz 12-Core Processor

Motherboard: Asus ROG Strix X570-E Gaming ATX AM4 Motherboard

Memory: Corsair Vengeance LPX 16 GB (2 x 8 GB) DDR4-3200 Memory

Video Card: Asus GeForce GTX 1080 8 GB ROG STRIX Video Card

Power Supply: EVGA 850 W 80+ Gold Certified Semi-modular ATX Power Supply

Comment: The _MicroSoft_ _Windows_ **10** Operating System is so feeble that even the slightest Software Update Package might mess it up completely, without even a single Hardware Change. In your case, since you have been digging so deeply into upgrading the Hardware Devices, I guess that a Clean Reinstallation Procedure is a _must_. I would not strive at all to debug why it is not working any longer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify that there is sufficient disk space to Hibernate and Sleep, now that RAM has been upgraded.
2. Use the following in CMD as Administrator [to set the size of *hiberfil.sys* to enable Hibernate](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/25151-specify-hiberfile-type-full-reduced-windows-10-a.html):

> powercfg /h /type full

3. Delete *hiberfil.sys, swapfile.sys,* and *pagefile.sys* (may need to be done from USB boot).
4. Try the following commands to Hibernate (they can be in CMD or as a .bat file, run as Administrator):

> powercfg -h on
>
> shutdown /h